# C++ enumerations and compiler dependency

Tags: c++, enums

I currently have code with an enum where one value is set and the rest are left to be set by the compiler using the previous value +1, or so I hope.

Is this functionality within an enumerated type compiler dependant, an example is below to clarify.

```
enum FUNC_ERROR_CODE    
{
    FUNC_SUCCESS,
    FUNC_ERROR_1 = 24,
    FUNC_ERROR_2,
    FUNC_ERROR_3
}
```

Is it safe to assume that FUNC_ERROR_2 will have the value 25 and FUNC_ERROR_3 will have the value 26, regardless of compliler used.

I'm coding this so as a function can return an integer value, 0 is always success and any other value can signify failure.

Comment: Why do you want to assume magic values? Can you not use the enum itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is safe to assume that:

- ***Enumeration Declaration [dcl.enum]***

  > The identifiers in an enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are
  >   required. An enumerator-definition with = gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the
  >   constant-expression. The constant-expression shall be of integral or enumeration type. **If the first
  >   enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition
  >   without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the *previous enumerator by one***.

**But** if you have a typesafe enum: *Use it*! Don't fall back on converting to/from integers.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, if your enums must have fixed values, then fix explicitely those values, you'll be sure of the values contained in your enums.

But if you only need to compare your enums each other, let the compiler do it for you.
It should be safe to write some comparisons like  this `if FUNC_ERROR_2 > FUNC_ERROR_1 ...`

Answer (score 1):

It is safe as far as Visual Studio 2010 goes. Check out the following example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx):

"*Any enumerator in the list, including the first one, can be initialized to a value other than its default value. Suppose the declaration of Suit had been the following:*

```
enum Suit {
   Diamonds = 5,
   Hearts,
   Clubs = 4,
   Spades
};
```

*Then the values of Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs, and Spades would have been **5, 6, 4, and 5,** respectively. Note that 5 is used more than once.*"

Comment: MSDN is not every compiler and it's not the standard. Never assume by means of a particular compiler that it is conforming to the standard.

Comment: @phresnel: MSDN is not every compiler, but that doesn't mean that it's _wrong_ either. It's still a valuable source of information on C++, and its much more readable (and freely available) than the C++ standard.

Comment: @phresnel: Updated the answer to specify that this is visual studio/msdn only.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, @Aveda Kedavra: It is not necessarily wrong, right. But the OP was about whether it is safe to assume that increment-by-one in an enum-declaration is portable. I am afraid it was *not* about MSVC in particular. Also, that quotation from MSDN does not even tell the rule, it tells just the result of typing down the example (-1 removed anyways)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the compiler is compelled to increment for each new value.